# Tomcat post special characters

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

In my maven project I have a html form that post data to a HttpServlet.
On the moment I post special characters in the html form (e.g. "jänsen", the HttpServlet receives "JÃ¤nsen".

I think I need to change settings to UTF-8 but I don't know where I have to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to configure `org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter` in your `web.xml` as next:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Set Character Encoding</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ignore</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Set Character Encoding</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

> Filter that sets the character encoding to be used in parsing the
>   incoming request, either unconditionally or only if the client did not
>   specify a character encoding.

More info about this filter [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/filters/SetCharacterEncodingFilter.html)