# How to Keep Russian characters on Input field on Submit

Tags: jsf

I have a download button that pushes a file to client :-

```
    <h:commandButton value="#{msg['lblBtnDownload']}" rendered="#{fileDownloadBean.showDownload}"
    action="#{fileDownloadBean.download}" styleClass="btnStyle"
    style="width:120px;">
```

However, there's a input text box which should expect russian text and its value is used in a query in the download process :-

```
    <h:inputText id="tpidRegex" value="#{fileDownloadBean.tpidRegex}" style="width:350px;"></h:inputText>
```

Now the value of `tpidRegex` I get is junk characters instead of the actual Russian text.

My faces-config.xml is :-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
version="2.1">

<application>
<locale-config>
   <default-locale>ru</default-locale>
   <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
</locale-config>
<resource-bundle>
  <base-name>com.messages</base-name>
  <var>msg</var>
 </resource-bundle>
</application>

<navigation-rule>
<from-view-id>/webgui/home.xhtml</from-view-id>
<navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>logout</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>logout.jsf?faces-redirect=true</to-view-id>
    <redirect />
</navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>

<navigation-rule>
<from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
<navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>home</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/webgui/home.jsf?faces-redirect=true</to-view-id>
    <redirect />
</navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>


</faces-config>
```

Comment: You probably need to configure your server with the correct encoding, what are you using?

Comment: Tomcat, I added parameter URIEncoding in connector tags as UTF-8

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38074567/1818198)